# How to pass a Count field to export field

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-import-export

I'm working on an export resource but I can't figure out how to pass this field from the view as a column in my export.

```
issues = Student.objects.annotate(Count('issue'))

def view_student(request):  
    issues = Student.objects.annotate(Count('issue'))
    students = Student.objects.filter(school = request.user.school).order_by('year')
    return render(request, 'view_student.html', {'students': students,'issues':issues})
```

This is how I tried it in the resoucrces.py but it shows no result

```
class ExportStudentsResource(resources.ModelResource):
    books = fields.Field(attribute = 'books',column_name='books',widget= ForeignKeyWidget(Student, 'issue_count'))
  
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('student_id','name','year','klass','stream','books')
```

This field is not from any model so I just thought Student model could be habouring it. How can I make it work

Answer (score 1):

You can override the [**`.get_queryset(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.ModelResource.get_queryset) and annotate your `Student` objects with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class ExportStudentsResource(resources.ModelResource):
    books = fields.Field(
        attribute='books',
        column_name='books',
        widget= ForeignKeyWidget(Student,'issue_count')
    )
    issues_count = fields.Field(attribute='issue_count')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            issue_count=Count('issue')
        )
  
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('student_id','name','year','klass','stream','books')
```